# Avoid page break inside in header table with rowspan not working (printing)

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table, puppeteer

I'm trying to generate a pdf with Puppeteer chrome.
The data in the pdf is dynamic.
The pdf contain multiple tables that I generate by looping through the data.
So, there are two loops, looping the tables and looping the data (`<td>`) inside each table.

The header of the table - inside `<thead>` - has `rowspan`. Unfortunately, the `<thead>` is not breaking as I expected.

Here is the current situation:

[image]

**expected result**

What I expect is that the `<thead>` wouldn't break.
If the `<thead>` does not fit, it should go to the next page.
I created the template using handlebars.

Here is the code of the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      min-height: 150mm !important;
      max-width: 297mm !important;
    }

    @page {
      size: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    {{#each array as |data|}}
    <table>
      <thead style="page-break-inside: avoid !important">
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">
            One
          </th>
          <th rowspan="2">
            Two
          </th>
          <th colspan="2">
            Three
          </th>
          <th rowspan="2">
            Four
          </th>
          <th rowspan="2">
            Five
          </th>
          <th colspan="2">
            Six
          </th>
          <th colspan="2">
            Seven
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Three child 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Three child 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Six child 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Six child 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Seven child 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Seven child 2
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each data.innerArray as |innerData|}}
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{innerData.one}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.two}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.three.one}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.three.two}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.four}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.five}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.six.one}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.six.two}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.seven.one}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{innerData.seven.two}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**I’ve tried**

1. I’ve tried to set `page-break-inside: avoid !important` inside the `<thead>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` but it's not working.
2. I’ve tried to wrap the `<thead>` with `<div>` and give `page-break-inside: avoid !important` to the div, still not working.

I don't know how to make this works. Any help, please?

**update**

I am open with answer that mix with plain javascript to solve this issue. I am thinking, could I try to detect the position of the `<thead>`, then, check if the `<thead>` is near (exact distance) the bottom of the page? If it match the condition, it will add style page-break-before true to that table only?

Comment: I'm wondering if you can make it work in something like Firefox to see if you approach should be working? I had an app that had to avoid breaking inside <tr>s but I just had to wait for chrome to support it.

Comment: @BillyHudson so you let the result "mess", until chrome fix itself, rite?

Comment: Filed a bug report, and found a way for users to work around it since it only happened sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Try limiting each column's width as `style="width: <somevalue>%;"` in total it should meet 100% like below code. Change the % values and split to the columns according to the amount of content you maintain inside each column.

**Example Code:**

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2" style="width: 10%;">
    One
  </th>
  <th rowspan="2" style="width: 20%;">
    Two
  </th>
  <th colspan="2" style="width: 20%;">
    Three
  </th>
  <th rowspan="2" style="width: 5%;">
    Four
  </th>
  <th rowspan="2" style="width: 5%;">
    Five
  </th>
  <th colspan="2" style="width: 20%;">
    Six
  </th>
  <th colspan="2" style="width: 20%;">
    Seven
  </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: thats not working. thanks for your reply. but I still face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<thead style="page-break-before">
```

This will ensure that each heading is on a new page and should work if you only have one heading per table.

The only issue to this solution is that you will have a fresh table on each page no matter how big/small the table is. However, it will stop the headings from breaking.

Alternatively there's also [This Article](https://htmlpdfapi.com/blog/using_css_page_breaks_when_converting_html_to_pdf) which further describes what you can do to stop page breaking from ruining tables.

Comment: sorry, but as you said, each fresh table will put in a new page. It is not what I expected. I've read the article that you mention. I've try to put `<div>` to wrap the two `<tr>` or wrap the `<thead>` with `<div>` and give style `page-break-inside: avoid`. But its not working.

Comment: Would you be able to try wrapping the entire table in the `<div>` with `page-break-inside: avoid!important` ?

I'm unable to replicate your PDF as I don't have the chrome extension. However, `page-break-inside` stops the element it's inside from breaking so I'm wondering if it's classing `h1` as the element.

Whereas if the element is the table itself it should avoid breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   table, td, th {
       border: 1px solid;
       padding: 10px;
       page-break-inside: avoid;
   }
   tr, td {
       word-wrap: break-word;
       page-break-inside: avoid;
       page-break-after: auto;
   }

    table thead {
        display: table-header-group
    }

    tfoot {
        display: table-footer-group
    }
```